# MySQL does not replicate, but it connects

Tags: mysql

I'm new to the subject. My problem is this: I am working with Bykom MySQL, on the one hand I have a working server and on the other hand I have an administrative server. In the administrative server I use it to create user accounts and the operating server is to work with those accounts. The problem is that I create an account in the administrative server but they are not reflected in the operating server, as they do not synchronize which is strange because in order to open the administrative server you need to have the operating server running. I need help, if someone can give me a hand I would appreciate it very much.

Both servers work with Windows Server 2008 r2.

Comment: What is Bykom?..

Comment: Bykom is a work platform. It is a program that uses our home alarm monitoring station.

Comment: exacto! Tengo un servidor administrativo (que se usa para agregar las cuentas de los clientes) y por otro lado tengo otro servidor (que es donde trabajan los operadores de monitoreo). Cuando quiero crear una cuenta para un cliente en el servidor administrativo, no se refleja en el servidor operativo.
Alguien me puede ayudar?